# How to sort std::multimap entries based on keys and values via custom Compare predicate?

Tags: c++, sorting, comparator, multimap

I'm looking for a way to sort `std::multimap`'s entries in **ascending order by keys**, but if the keys match, in **descending order by values**.

Is it possible to implement with a custom [`Compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) predicate?

Comment: An ordered map (or multimap) isn't hashed, it's usually implemented as an RB-tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map's `Compare` predicate only takes **keys** as arguments. Unfortunately you cannot use **values** to sort the entries within the same bucket with use of the predicate only.

**Important** - it's still possible to implement such scenario it with other means. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33406365/5690248) is the answer how to do it if you are ok to use `emplace_hint`.

---

The keys are sorted in ascending order by default with use of [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less). In order to implement a custom predicate, you can use a lambda (or any other form of the binary predicate):

```
const auto lessPredicate = [](const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) {
    return lhs.value < rhs.value;
};
std::multimap<MyClass, std::string, decltype(lessPredicate)> my_map { lessPredicate };
```